# LinkedIn laravel callback authentication

Tags: laravel, rest, linkedin-api

I have worked with LinkedIn API. The API working properly till on 26th April 2018.

Now, we could not able OAuth the LinkedIn.

We are using Laravel package to OAuth the LinkedIn.

When i was debugging the code then i get the following error from oauth response

```
Array
(
    [error] => server_error
    [error_description] => the authorization server encountered an unexpected condition
)
```

Please advise?

Comment: What did you try so far? Please add a link in your question to the package you are using. Which Laravel / package version are you using?

Comment: use Laravel Socialite Package , see this link : https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-5-login-with-linkedin-using-socialite-packageexample.html